# GCC Linking "undefined reference" with third part Shared Object (.so) file

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker

Banging my head against a wall with making a quick proof of concept app which links to a third party .so file.

I've produces a simple C file which calls a simple function in the .so file, it includes the header file also supplied by the vendor. Linking produces the following errors:

```
/usr/local/lib/xxx.so: undefined reference to `sprintf_s'
/usr/local/lib/xxx.so: undefined reference to `sendWCmdThread'
/usr/local/lib/xxx.so: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/local/lib/xxx.so: undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'
```

I can handle the pthread issues (-pthread option) but I'm at a loss for the other two errors. Expecially as Google provides zero results for 'sendWCmdThread'

Anyone help?

Comment: Ask the third party.

Comment: Can you add the command you used to compile to the question?

Comment: isn't `sprintf_s`  the "safe" version of `sprintf` ?

Comment: Please produce a [mcve] and show how you compile it (and I would start with `sprintf_s` problem only).

Comment: `sprintf_s` has been introduced with C11. Are you sure to compile with `--std=c11` ?

Comment: @MichaelBeer It also requires `#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1` And is not necessarily supported even with `c11`

Comment: Anyhow, perhaps the provider of your 3rd party library supports  pkg-config ( https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config ). Then you should be able to invoke the gcc something like `gcc my_c_file.c $(pkg-config --cflags --lib my_third_party_library)` .

Comment: `sprintf_s` is AFAIK not available in Linux. Maybe the 3rd party also provides a compat library. Go ask them. As to google, it's fixed now -- it already provides 1 result for `sendWCmdThread` ;-)